# Objective C - Custom Storyboard Segue Black Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom storyboard segue which presents views from right to left. But during the animation, there is a momentary black screen that shows which makes for a bit of a jagged experience.

Here's my code:

```
    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    srcViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    UIViewController *destViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.1;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [srcViewController.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [srcViewController presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your destViewController, in viewDidLoad, sets the background color of its view to something:

```
//DestViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Or alternatively, and I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but my fit better into your code:

```
UIViewController *destViewController = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;
destViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//Now do all the CATransitions, etc.
```